# WPF - Is it possible to create a shared base window class, that is both chromeless and resizable?

Tags: wpf

I can create a standard WPF window as follows, and all works fine.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWindowStyleTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Background="Transparent"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
        TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"
        Topmost="True"
        UseLayoutRounding="True"
        WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="LightGreen"
                BorderBrush="Navy"
                BorderThickness="2"
                CornerRadius="4">

            // window content here ...

        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

However, my application requires a number of common components (way beyond a simple border) to be shared by all windows, so I tried to extract it into a common class.

```
public class BaseView: Window
{
    static BaseView()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BaseView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BaseView)));
    }
}
```

with the following style in generic.xaml

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}" TargetType="{x:Type local:BaseView}">
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight" />
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextRenderingMode" Value="ClearType" />
    <Setter Property="Topmost" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:BaseView}">
                <Grid>
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <Border Background="LightGreen"
                                BorderBrush="Navy"
                                BorderThickness="2"
                                CornerRadius="4">

                            <ContentPresenter Margin="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        </Border>
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This works fine.

However, when I add another property setter to the style

```
<Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip" />
```

The whole control template is ignored, and just the specified window content is displayed (in an empty, resizable window).

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Do you want to remove chrome and make your window without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue depends on the standard `Window` style; take a look:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type Window}" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}">
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Window.ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template" Value="{StaticResource ħ}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

As you can see, if the `ResizeMode` is set to `CanResizeWithGrip`, a trigger changes the `Window`'s template.

A simple solution could be adding a `ResizeGrip` to your template and avoing that your style inherits from the default one. Something like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:BaseView}">
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight" />
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextRenderingMode" Value="ClearType" />
    <Setter Property="Topmost" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />

    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:BaseView}">
                <Grid>
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <Border Background="LightGreen"
                            BorderBrush="Navy"
                            BorderThickness="2"
                            CornerRadius="4">

                            <ContentPresenter Margin="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        </Border>
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                    <ResizeGrip Name="WindowResizeGrip" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsTabStop="False" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I hope it can help you.